# (dotnet core) Best way to build function used by both scoped and singleton services

Tags: .net-core, dry

I have a function that I want to use in both a singleton service and a scoped service.  My question is, should I build it as a static function, copy/paste it into both services, or create the scope within the service calling it?

This is more of a best practices question.  Currently, I have the function pasted in both services, but I generally subscribe to DRY, which this isn't.  So the question is, what is the best way to put this stateless function into the code?